# GitHub API always returns open milestones even when I request closed ones

Tags: python, json, github-api

I am trying to get a list of **all** milestones, whether they are open or closed. I do this with a simple while loop:

```
milestoneNumbers = {}

for state in ['open', 'closed']:
    print("***" + state)
    stateJSON = {'state' : state}
    print(json.dumps(stateJSON))
    response = requests.get(
        'https://api.github.com/repos/' + username + '/' + repo + '/milestones',
        data=json.dumps(stateJSON),
        auth=(username, password))

    milestones = response.json()
    for milestone in milestones:
        print(milestone['title'] + " " + str(milestone['number']))
        milestoneNumbers[milestone['title']] = milestone['number']

print(milestoneNumbers)
```

The problem is that this returns the open milestones twice. What am I doing wrong here?

OUTPUT:

> open
>   {"state": "open"}
>   wiki pages 6
>   android 7
>   swing 0.5.4 16
>   lite 0.5.7 18
>   project 19
>   swing 20
>   premium 10
>   lite 0.5.6 15
>   closed
>   {"state": "closed"}
>   wiki pages 6
>   android 7
>   swing 0.5.4 16
>   lite 0.5.7 18
>   project 19
>   swing 20
>   premium 10
>   lite 0.5.6 15
>   {u'project': 19, u'premium': 10, u'wiki pages': 6, u'lite 0.5.7': 18, u'lite 0.5.6': 15, u'swing 0.5.4': 16, u'swing': 20, u'android': 7}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing a `GET` request; don't send JSON but URL parameters:

```
response = requests.get(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/' + username + '/' + repo + '/milestones',
    params={'state': state},
    auth=(username, password))
```

This sends the state as a *GET* parameter. The `data` keyword parameter is entirely ignored when using `GET` anyway, so the parameter never made it to the GitHub server and it defaulted to `'state': 'open'` in absence of a specific value.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. Will accept when the timer is up.

Comment: Do I also use `params` for a PATCH request?